# how to select values in the dropdown box

Tags: javascript

this is my code .
if i select tamilnadu , i must get chennai.
if i select kerla i must get kochi.
how to get the values if i submit.

```
enter code here
<td align='center' >STATE:</td>
        <td> <select name ='state' onchange="showData()">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="TAMILNADU">TAMILNADU</option>
            <option value="KERLA">KERLA</option>
            <option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</option>
            </td>

    </tr>
    <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align='center' name ='city'>city:</td>
        <td> <select>
        <option id='chennai'>chennai</option>
        <option id='kochi'>kochi</option>
        <option id='banglore'>banglore<option>
    </tr>
```

Comment: i must validate without using form tag .... can u tell me how to get the values

Comment: Have you any javasript?

Comment: You could start with valid markup.

Comment: function showData(){
 var theSelect='state';
 var chennai=document.getElementById('chennai');
 var kochi=document.getElementById('kochi');
 var banglore= document.getElementById('banglore');
 chennai.select=(theSelect.selectedIndex='TAMILNADU');
 kochi.select=(selectedIndex='KERLA');

Comment: im trying in javascript not sure if this above code is correct

Comment: @SanthoshRaja : Plz check if that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the correct tag formation like this:

**jQuery**

```js
$('#state').change(function() {
  $('#res').html($('#city option').eq($('#state option:selected').index()).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td align='center'>STATE:</td>
  <td>
    <select name='state' id='state'>
      <option value="TAMILNADU">TAMILNADU</option>
      <option value="KERLA">KERLA</option>
      <option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</option>
    </select>
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align='center' name='city'>city:</td>
  <td>
    <select name='city' id='city'>
      <option id='chennai'>chennai</option>
      <option id='kochi'>kochi</option>
      <option id='banglore'>banglore
        <option>
    </select>
</tr>
<br>
<br>RESULT : <span id='res'></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
function listResult() {
  var e = document.getElementById("state");
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = document.getElementById("city").options[e.selectedIndex].value


}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td align='center'>STATE:</td>
  <td>
    <select name='state' id='state' onchange='listResult()'>
      <option value="TAMILNADU">TAMILNADU</option>
      <option value="KERLA">KERLA</option>
      <option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</option>
    </select>
  </td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align='center' name='city'>city:</td>
  <td>
    <select name='city' id='city'>
      <option id='chennai'>chennai</option>
      <option id='kochi'>kochi</option>
      <option id='banglore'>banglore
        <option>
    </select>
</tr>
<br>
<br>RESULT : <span id='res'></span>
```